# Building dynamic library from Visual studio files

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, extending

I am writing a C++ module for Python3. To make Python working with it, I have to build C++ source into dynamic library (one of the requirements is windows-compatibility).

The source code is correctly compiled and linked with Cmake (my cmake generator is  Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64). But then I have to build `.dll` file from Cmake files. The list of Cmake files if here:
[image]

Note, there isn't Makefile in this list!

How can I build `.dll` from this files? I tried MinGW and GNUwin32, but trey weren't working.

My CMakeLists.txt is below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILES on)
project(Proj)
set(SOURCE_FILES repeating_count.cpp)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
python_add_module(repeating_count repeating_count.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
add_executable(Proj ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Proj ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: `Note, there isn't Makefile in this list!` There is not supposed to be a makefile on visual studio. You have everything you need to build in the ide. You can even open a visual studio command prompt and do `cmake --build .` from the folder containing  the .sln file or use msbuild.

Comment: @drescherjm, ok, I used VS command promt and catch an error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python34_d.lib' [D:\VeLKerr\Docum
ents\proglangs\Build\repeating_count.vcxproj]`

Comment: @VeLKerr I believe the comment was not related to your actual problem. The error you're seeing comes from the fact that by default for VS `cmake --build .` will build the debug version. You need to run `cmake --build . --config Release` to biuld the release version.

Comment: @Rostislav, I tried to build release instead of debug, but only got `python34.lib` istead of `python34_d.lib` in error message. I have both, `python34.lib` and `python34_d.lib` on my PC.

Comment: @VeLKerr Apparently, your CMakeLists.txt is missing some stuff. Seeing it would help figuring this out.

Comment: @Rostislav, I updated my posts with CMakeLists.txt (in this file I also took into account your ansver).

Comment: Well, a couple of things. VS doesn't have a flag "-std=c++11". It will build with all the available features by default (if you're using VS2015 it will have almost all C++14 and some C++17 as well). Looking at python's docs it seems that you just need to make a dll. I'll edit my answer with what I think your CMakeLists should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using CMake, you can achieve this by adding

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
```

before you define your libraries (perhaps, simply in the beginning of your CMakeLists.txt). See documentation of this flag [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html).

Alternatively, you can directly force a library to be shared by adding a `SHARED` flag to you `add_library`:

```
add_library(myLibrary SHARED ${sources})
```

See documentation regarding this [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_library.html).

Your modified CMakeLists should then look like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILES on)
project(Proj)
set(SOURCE_FILES repeating_count.cpp)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

# Find PythonLibs
find_package(PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# This will create the Proj.dll
add_library(Proj ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Proj ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Regarding the `-std=c++11` flag - you don't need that for MSVS generator. If you're really interested in the correct way to ensure `c++XX` flags are enabled for any generator, take a look at [target_compile_features](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html).

Comment: I edited CMakeLists.txt (see it in the end of my post), but building fails with error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python34.lib'`